# How can I add hyperlinks to a JTextPane without html?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane with a StyledDocument "doc" and I want when I `doc.isertString(doc.getLength(), "http://www.google.com", attrs)`
the JTextPane to show a hyperlink that can be clicked. I put "http://www.google.com" and attrs  as an example because I really have no idea how to go about it. Surprisingly, I couldn't find anything useful online(without html, or HTMLDocument, etc.). I don't like how swing works with html and I prefer not to use it.

```
public class SSCCE extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SSCCE frame = new SSCCE();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public SSCCE() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        try {
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "http://www.google.com", attrs);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(textPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 422, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(textPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 248, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your own `AttributeSet` to keep hyperlink info. It should include e.g. blue color and custom attribute. Let's name it "URL". Add some text with the `AttributeSet` to the `StyledDocument`.

Then add a mouse listeners (Both motion and mouse listener). For any mouse event you can use `viewToModel()` to get offset for specified mouse position. Get a leaf element (text) for the offset and check whether the text `Element` has the attributes.

If it has do your actions (e.g. set mouse cursor to hand or process click on the URL).

Answer (score 4):

+1 to StanislavL answer.Here is simple approach **using** HTML.
Well its not complicated to use `HTML` tags in your java code.The other way round may be complicated.I have done a short EG, easy to perform and understand,you can modify it and make it fit for your purpose.

[image]

CODE:

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class JlabelLink extends JFrame {
private JPanel pan;

    private JLabel website;

public JlabelLink() {
    this.setTitle("jLabelLinkExample");
    this.setSize(300, 100);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    pan = new JPanel();

    website = new JLabel();


    website.setText("<html> Website : <a href=\"\">http://www.google.com/</a></html>");
    website.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));


    pan.add(website);
    this.setContentPane(pan);
    this.setVisible(true);

    goWebsite(website);
 }


  public static void main(String args[]) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new JlabelLink().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    }

  private void goWebsite(JLabel website) {
    website.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            try {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com/webhp?nomo=1&hl=fr"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JlabelLink.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            catch (URISyntaxException ex) {

            }
         }
       });
    }
   }
```